# How to execute script function inside React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to implement 4 scripts, the last one has one function that I always get undefined, I have implemented it on a website without React, but at react I'm having a lot of problems.

```
componentDidMount () {
   this.mountLeadpointScript();
}

  mountLeadpointScript() {
    const disclosureScript = document.createElement('script');
    disclosureScript.id = 'disclosureSr';
    disclosureScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    disclosureScript.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(disclosureScript);

    const srScript = document.createElement('script');
    srScript.id = 'srScript';
    srScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    srScript.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(srScript);

    const dataVerifyScript = document.createElement('script');
    dataVerifyScript.src = '"//www.dataverify123.com/js/sr-min.js';
    dataVerifyScript.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(dataVerifyScript);

    dataVerifyScript.onload = () => {
      window.leadpoint_dataLayer = [{    'a': '00000',    'i': '11111'  }];
      window.LeadpointSecureRights.startSrTokenProcess('www.dataverify123.com');
    }
  }
```

- Not displaying the real values of a & i.

Always getting undefined, i have tried withouth window, using this, putting it on the html of the app, nothing works.

Thanks in advance.

I'll attach a picture of how it should be implemented [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AHOX.png)

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @Salah worked, I was trying to display a disclaimer from that script and it wasn't working due that the div wasn't being rendered when the script was executing, at the end, I ended up using a set timeout so the component will be rendered and then the script is going to execute correctly.

Otherwise, if there is a solution where I can avoid using it on the HTML would be great.

Answer (score -1):

well, to solve that, you may have to paste those scripts in the `index.html` file, if you are using `create-react-app`, you will find it in: `public/index.html`.
Hope that helps